# Django generic create view default value for model choice field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-generic-views

I have a view that inherits from the generic CreateView and overrides the get_initial method like so:

```
class PosterVisualCreateView (ModelFormMixin, generic.edit.CreateView, ObjectClassContextMixin):
    model = Poster
    valid_message = "Successfully created object."
    template_name = "poser/create_poster_visual.html"

    def get_form_class (self):
        return super(PosterVisualCreateView, self).get_form_class(extra="CreateVisual")

    def get_form_kwargs (self):
        kwargs = super(PosterVisualCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()

        kwargs.update({
            "company": self.request.company
        })
        return kwargs

    def get_context_data (self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PosterVisualCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            "company": self.request.company,
        })
        return context

    def get_initial (self):
        initial = super(PosterVisualCreateView, self).get_initial()
        initial.update({
            "company": self.request.company,
            "template": self.request.company.template_set.all().first()
        })
        return initial

    def form_valid(self, form):
        success_url = super(PosterVisualCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
        attributes = form.instance.create_attributes()
        for attribute in attributes:
            attribute.poster = form.instance
            attribute.save()
        form.instance.save()
        form.instance.render_html(commit=True)
        form.instance.save()
        return success_url

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch (self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PosterVisualCreateView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

The page renders this form:

```
class PosterFormCreateVisual (CompanyHiddenForm):
    """Create form for Posters."""
    template = fields.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, queryset=Template.objects.all())
    product = fields.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, queryset=Product.objects.all(),
        required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Poster
        fields = ("template", "product", "company")

    def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):
        company = kwargs.pop("company", None)
        assert company is not None, "Company is required to create attribute form."
        super(PosterFormCreateVisual, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["template"].queryset = company.template_set.all()
        self.fields["product"].queryset = company.product_set.all()
```

The initial value should be the first item in the radio selection for template but this isn't the case, can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Try `"template": Template.objects.all()[0]` in `get_initial`

Comment: Not all templates belong to the current company so don't want the first template out of all templates in the system selected as default as it may not belong to the user.

Comment: I see. Have you tried without the '.id', setting it just to the model object? It's been a while since I used get_initial, but I think you may not want to use the id.

Comment: Also in your current code, is company's initial appearing in form correctly?

Comment: Company is hidden in the form as it's not choosable, it's decided by your current login. Removing .id makes no difference.

Comment: Can you use Chrome debug console to see if the company hidden field is getting set correctly?

Comment: It is `<input id="id_company" name="company" type="hidden" value="3">`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"template": self.request.company.template_set.all().first()
```

But as far as I understand you original code should work too.

BTW, how you tested the form?  By hitting the "Refresh" button or `Ctrl-R`/`F5` key?  Some browsers reload page but save the previously selected/entered form values.  To check initial values you should reload the form page by clicking on the address bar (or pressing `Ctrl-L`) and then pressing the `Enter` key.

Comment: I tested it with a sample model/form and it works fine.  Update the question with the full code of the view and template, please.

Comment: Hm, I can't even run this code.  `ModelFormMixin` clashes with `CreateView` (Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO)).  And `get_form_class()` has no such argument as `extra`.  I am afraid that can't help here, sorry.

Comment: the `extra` argument ensures the form class fetched is PosterFormCreateVisual i.e `"PosterForm"+"CreateVisual"` rather than the default PosterForm.